# Android ListView exclude section headers from being highlighted

Tags: android, android-listview, sticky, sectionheader

I have recently implemented the [StickyListHeadersListview](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library from github. Then I used MultiChoiceModeListener for selecting items and then to copy or delete those selected elements as seen below

I don't want the section headers (date field) to get highlighted. Is there any way to disable this behaviour.

This question originated from my last unanswered question. Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781326/stickylistheaderslistview-multichoicemode-issue) for custom array adapter code

[image]

Comment: Did you tried changing the background color of `convetview` in the `getHeaderView()` method?

Comment: @Boss Haven't tried yet.. Thanks I'll try that

Comment: @Boss convertView.setBackground(Color.TRANSPARENT) did the trick.. can you please post it as an answer with explanation so that I can mark it as the accepted answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change the background color of your view using
>   `View.setBackgroundColor();` method.

In your `getHeaderView()` method add this line

> convertView.setBackgroundColor(your color)

```
  @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
           holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.date_separator, parent, false);

            convertView.setBackgroundColor(your color);// change here

         }                

         return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Why it is not getting highlighted after changing the colour.. It will be good if you explain that too